# How can I put the loading while waiting on render Reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, web

I just made an animated "loading.." using css but i want it to only exist when it's waiting for data to load/render.. any idea how I really dont know how im so new to this?...

this is my componentdidmount

```
componentDidMount() {
  $.ajax({
  url:'http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/getemployeedetails/',
  success:(data)=>{

    this.setState({
      jsonReturnedValue:data
    })
  }
})
  this.setState({isLoading: false})   
}
```

this is my render

```
renderItem(d, i) {
  return <tr key={i} >
    <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
    <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
    <td>{d.Address }</td> 
    <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleOnclick.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID, d.Employee_Name, d.Address , d.Department , i)}   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
    <td><center><button className ='btn btn-danger'  onClick={this.handleOnclick2.bind (this,d.Employee_ID,d.Employee_Name,i)} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteEmployee"> Delete</button></center></td>
    </tr>
}

render() {
      if(this.state.isLoading) {
           return <span className="Loader">
          <div className="Loader-indicator" >
            <h1>
              <span>Loading</span>
              <span className="Loader-ellipsis" >
                <span className="Loader-ellipsisDot">.</span>
                <span className="Loader-ellipsisDot">.</span>
                <span className="Loader-ellipsisDot">.</span>
              </span>
            </h1>
          </div>
        </span>
     }

    let {jsonReturnedValue} = this.state;
    const isEnabled = this.canBeSubmitted();


  return(
    <div>
    <div>

        <div className="container">   
          <h1> Listof Employees </h1>
            <button className ='btn btn-warning right ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEmployee"> Add an Employee</button>
             <table className= "table table-bordered" id="result"> 
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Address</th>
                      <th>Update</th>
                      <th>Delete</th>
                 </tr>
                    {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))}
                </tbody>

            </table>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain a state in your react component that is set to true whenever you give a call to load the data

Eg

```
class App extends React.Component {
     constructor(){
         super();
         this.state = {isLoading: true}
     }


componentDidMount() {


   $.ajax({
      url:'http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/getemployeedetails/',
      success:(data)=>{ 
        this.setState({
           jsonReturnedValue:data, isLoading: false
        })
      }
   })

}

render() {
     if(this.state.isLoading) {
           return <span className="Loader">
          <div className="Loader-indicator" >
            <h1>
              <span>Loading</span>
              <span className="Loader-ellipsis" >
                <span className="Loader-ellipsisDot">.</span>
                <span className="Loader-ellipsisDot">.</span>
                <span className="Loader-ellipsisDot">.</span>
              </span>
            </h1>
          </div>
        </span>
     }
     return (
         <div>Hello World</div>
     )

}
```

See a demo snippet

```js
class App extends React.Component {
         constructor(){
             super();
             this.state = {isLoading: true}
         }
    
    
    componentDidMount() {
  
       setTimeout(() => {this.setState({isLoading: false})}, 3000)
      
    }
    
    render() {
         if(this.state.isLoading) {
               return <span className="Loader">
              <div className="Loader-indicator" >
                <h1>
                  <span>Loading</span>
                  <span className="Loader-ellipsis" >
                    <span className="Loader-ellipsisDot">.</span>
                    <span className="Loader-ellipsisDot">.</span>
                    <span className="Loader-ellipsisDot">.</span>
                  </span>
                </h1>
              </div>
            </span>
         }
         return (
             <div>Hello World</div>
         )
     
    }
}    
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: It will output your data when you set the loading state to false as I did in my case. Your data will do at a place where I have `return (
         <div>Hello World</div>
     )`

Comment: i did the same thing you put however instead of hello world it output my table but it wasn't working it still loading..

Comment: Are you doing this after your data has loaded `this.setState({isLoading: false})`

Comment: i put it under my ajax in componentdidmount

Comment: Can you add that part in your question

Comment: sure, just added it

Comment: See my updated snippet , also check if you get any error in console once data is available

Comment: its working now it turns out my construct i put is wrong

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: just a question how can i put it under the table when its waiting for other part of the table?

Comment: Add another state tableLoading, then inside `<tbody>{this.state.tableLoading? (loading code here): map and call this.renderItem() here}`

Comment: im confuse .. sorry im just so new to this

Comment: See you have to do the same thing, but since you can't use if-else in return, you need to make use of ternary operator and where you were having ` {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))}` at the same place add `{this.state.tableLoading? <LoadingComponent/>: this.renderItem()}`

Comment: However now you would need to map in the renderItem instead of calling renderItem from map

Comment: i see .. map like the jsonreturnvalue?

Answer (score 0):

add `loading` state, and make it true, when data is loaded.

in `render()` function make add loading state code, using `?` operator.

```
{this.state.loading ? (<YourComponent />) : (<LoadingState />)}
```

replace `<YourComponent />` and `<LoadingState />` with your component or needed jsx tags...

Comment: im confuse on your explanation

Comment: nvm, Shubham Khatri write same concept